# Swift 3 - PHFetchResult - enumerateObjects - Ambiguous use of 'enumerate objects'

Tags: swift, swift3

Not so sure why I'm getting "Ambiguous use of 'enumerate objects' in Swift 3.

```
let collections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .moment, subtype: .any, options: nil)

    collections.enumerateObjects { (collection, start, stop) in
        collection as! PHAssetCollection
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: nil)
        assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
            content.append(object)
        })

    }
```

Any thoughts? This code was working fine in Swift 2.2

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have run into this a few times myself, and it appears to be an issue with Swift's trailing closure syntax. Including parentheses around the closure argument should do the trick:

```
collections.enumerateObjects({ (collection, start, stop) in
    collection as! PHAssetCollection
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: nil)
    assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
        content.append(object)
    })

})
```

**Edit:** Please see rintaro's answer for an explanation of why this happens.

Comment: Thank you for that! It was driving me insane.

Comment: Thank you! you saved my day!

Comment: Thanks you!!!!! The weirdest part is that if you follow autocompletion on Xcode, it will still give you an erroneous behavior.... This did the trick!!

Comment: @RaphaelAyres technically there's nothing wrong with Xcode auto completion there, but it just currently seems to be a bug in the Swift Compiler or possibly Xcode.

Answer (score 9):

When using `enumerateObjects` with trailing closure,
there are two overloaded candidates for it:

- [`enumerateObjects(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phfetchresult/1620999-enumerateobjects)
- [`enumerateObjects(options:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phfetchresult/1621006-enumerateobjects)(because `options:` is defaulted)

Currently, *we* need to disambiguate this.

If you want to use trailing closure syntax, here's the workaround:

```
assets.enumerateObjects(_:) { (object, count, stop) in
    content.append(object)
}
```

This works because this is equivalent to

```
let unapplied = assets.enumerateObjects(_:)
unapplied { (object, count, stop) in
    content.append(object)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the intuition on that. Would you still say that it is a bug that Xcode does not automatically detect which function version we want?

Comment: Great answer describing the terrifyingly complicated reality. @MatthewSeaman it's not a bug: it's how all this inference stuff is supposed to work.